# Linked list addLast method

Tags: java, linked-list, addition

How can I build an `addLast` method in Java? I already know `LinkedList` has a built-in method which does this)

This is what I've tried:

```
public void addFirst(int d1, double d2) { 
    Link link = new Link(d1, d2); 
    link.nextLink = first; 
    first = link;
        }
public void addLast(int d1 , double d2){
    Link v = new Link(d1, d2);
    v.nextLink = null;
    tail.nextLink = v;
   tail = v
```

}

```
    public void printList() { 
    Link currentLink = first; 
    System.out.print("List: "); 
    while(currentLink != null) { 
    currentLink.printlink(); 
    currentLink = currentLink.nextLink; 
    } 
        System.out.println(""); 
}
```

My `addFirst` method works, but I don't know how to connect them.

in the main :

```
    LinkList list = new LinkList();  
         list.addFirst(4, 4.04); 
         list.addFirst(5, 5.05); 
         list.addlast(3,4.5);
         list.printList();
```

Answer (score 3):

I realize that this is a school assignment so without giving the answer here are the steps to follow:

1. check if list is empty
2. if list is empty set head + tail to point to same node
3. Iterate over all elements
4. Update tail to new node

Also there is no way that the addFirst method you have above would work you are constantly resetting the value in tail.

Comment: there is no need to iterate over all elements when appending an element to the end of the list. He has the tail reference...

Comment: Let me rephrase that, he did not do sufficient checking to prove that the tail reference was ever set in his methods.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem appears to be in the last line. You want

```
tail = v;
```

Not

```
v = tail;
```

Furthermore, You have

```
tail = link
```

as the last line of your addFirst method - it's not clear why you're doing this. You shouldn't need to update the tail of the list as you add to the front.

Comment: It's not clear why that would be the case. Maybe you should update the original post to include your new code?

Comment: Yep PFHayes corrections should do the trick. If your test code still returns false there may be a bug in the test code or in another part of your code.

Comment: It seems like the tail of your list is not actually an entry in the list. Effectively what you are doing now is that you are maintaining two seperate linked lists, one starting at first, and one ending at tail. What you need is to add code that, when you are adding an item to an empty list, then both first and tail are initialized to that item.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void addLast(int d1, double d2){

    Node node = new Node(d1, d2);
    Node temp = first;
    while(temp.next!= null) {
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    temp.next = node;
}
```